# How to merge subsets of data frames from a list (i.e., merge all of the first dfs from each list component)

Tags: r, list, merge

I have seen a number of answers as to how to merge dataframes from a list when each list element is a single data frame.  However, in my case, each list element contains two data frames.  I want to merge all of the first together and all of the second.  As a dummy example:

```
lst<-list()
lst[[1]]<-list(data.frame(cat=c(1:5), type=c(11:15)), data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), num=c(1:3)))
lst[[2]]<-list(data.frame(cat=c(22:26), type=c(50:54)), data.frame(group=c("H","I","J"), num=c(7:9)))
```

I want to merge the first elements together and the second elements together, to yield two data frames:

```
df1:
cat type
1   1   11
2   2   12
3   3   13
4   4   14
5   5   15
6  22   50
7  23   51
8  24   52
9  25   53
10  26   54

df2:
group num
1     A   1
2     B   2
3     C   3
4     H   7
5     I   8
6     J   9
```

I am sure there is some straightforward way to do this (somehow with do.call and rbind??) but I cannot figure out how to reference the various elements within each list properly.

Clearly with this small example I could just do it manually by:

```
df1<-rbind(lst[[1]][[1]], lst[[2]][[1]])
```

However, my actual list includes hundreds of data frames. I can do it by creating a loop and rbinding in one at a time sequentially, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way...Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` function(where you can customize how to `reduce` it) to `rbind` data frames. `Reduce` takes two elements from the list every time and reduce it to one element based on your function, and for the customized `rbind` since each two data frames need to be bound separately, you can use `Map`, put them together:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) Map(rbind, x, y), lst)

# [[1]]
#    cat type
# 1    1   11
# 2    2   12
# 3    3   13
# 4    4   14
# 5    5   15
# 6   22   50
# 7   23   51
# 8   24   52
# 9   25   53
# 10  26   54

# [[2]]
#   group num
# 1     A   1
# 2     B   2
# 3     C   3
# 4     H   7
# 5     I   8
# 6     J   9
```

Or maybe a faster way:

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `[[`, i)))
```

Comment: Any idea why the second option doesn't work with `sapply` ?

Comment: @RonakShah `do.call(rbind, ...)` requires a list as argument and `sapply` returns a matrix in this case.

Comment: Ohkay. Was stuck thinking why `sapply(1:2, function(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `[[`, i)))` doesn't work. Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks so much, Psidom!  Both work, but the second does seem to be slightly faster on larger lists. I really appreciate it!